# Android - Passing a parameter to google play to be invoked when an app is opened after installation

Tags: android, google-play

Our product has an option to share content using a link. Imagine the link is received in an email. Now a user clicks on the link. If the app is installed, the app catches the link and opens the content.

If the app is not installed a web page appears and shows an option to install the app. The user clicks that option, get redirected to google play, installs the app and opens the app.

BUT, the original link that points to the desired content wasn't passed to Google play. So the user needs to get back to the mail and click the link again. In the short term, it's like a punishment to install an app.

**Is there a way to pass the link (info) to the freshly installed app?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do something close with an extra layer of indirection and Google+ Sign In. Let's say instead of taking them to the Play Store when the app is not installed, you have a Google+ Sign In page that offers to install the app when the user signs in (and the user is automatically signed-in on the app that gets installed). When the user signs in on the web, you could persist the link, and then simply restore it based on the logged-in account when the user opens the app on the their device. Granted, this is not as slick as immediately opening the link in the app, but I don't think that is doable.